# Bitbucket Branch Restriction (name pattern)

Tags: git, bitbucket

How can I restrict commits or pull requests to a branch pattern. For Example:

I want to restrict this pattern release/sprint-*

But

I want to enable release/sprint-35

If I give this pattern release/sprint-* and even when I define another restriction for release/sprint-35, the first pattern effects the other one. On top of it doesn't accept a regex or something like that

So is there a way to achieve it, rather than giving separate restriction for each branch.

Thanks in advance.